# (can we write multiple update and insert statements with in stored procedure and execute it ) using bcp util?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Example of Queries

```
/* insert Statement */

insert into ExecutionClass(ExecutionTitle,MachineName,ProjectName,ExecutedBy,TimestampId) select top 1 ExecutionTitle, MachineName,ProjectName,ExecutedBy,TimestampId from PrimaryStaging where TimestampId=12345678910 and MachineName = Pc'; 

/* Update Start and End Time */
update ExecutionClass set StartTime = (select min(StartTime) from PrimaryStaging where TimestampId=12345678910 and MachineName='Stellium-PC') where TimestampId=12345678910 and MachineName='Pc'

update ExecutionClass set EndTime = (select max(EndTime) from PrimaryStaging where TimestampId=12345678910 and MachineName='PC') where TimestampId=12345678910 and MachineName='Pc'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: In reference with this :
bcp "SELECT * from Application.People WHERE FullName = 'Amy Trefl'" queryout D:\BCP\Amy_Trefl_c.bcp -d WideWorldImporters -c -T

Comment: Not sure how that is explaining anything. You asked about a stored procedure with multiple statements being executed with bcp. The above query is neither a stored procedure nor multiple statements.

Comment: But bcp does not execute stored procedures. You would need to use sqlcommand for that. But it is difficult to determine what you are really asking.

Comment: 1st aim : is to update / insert into  my database rows using bcp util.

Comment: 2nd aim : is to do the bulk update and insert statements using stored procedure.

Comment: What? So you want to first run two scripts on their own and then call a stored procedure? And why do you think you need bcp for this?

Comment: I am using bcp as it can be automated. the sql's that i am triggering in can be automatically generated using the tool i am using and instead of manually executing them in sql management studio im taking the help of bcp as it can be automated. Please let me know how you can update any record of the table using BCP Util.

Comment: I think perhaps you might want to read about the bcp utility. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility I don't think it is does what you think it does. Again...look at sqlcommand.